# Word add-in js - Unable to write to new document

Tags: office365, ms-office, office-js, office-addins, word-addins

I'm trying to create a Word add-in using Office JS which looks at content in the current opened document and then creates a new document and writes to this new document. Here's a code snippet of what I'm trying to do:

```
            var myNewDoc = context.application.createDocument();
            context.load(myNewDoc);
            var body = myNewDoc.body;
            body.insertText('some text', Word.InsertLocation.end);
```

When I run this however I get the following error:

```
Debug info: {"code":"NotAllowed","message":"The action isn’t supported in Word Online. Check the OfficeExtension.Error.debugInfo for more information.","errorLocation":"DocumentCreated.body","statement":"var body=createDocument.body;","surroundingStatements":["var v=Microsoft.WordServices.Application.newObject();","var createDocument=v.createDocument();","// Instantiate {createDocument}","// >>>>>","var body=createDocument.body;","// <<<<<","// Instantiate {body}"],"fullStatements":["Please enable config.extendedErrorLogging to see full statements."]}
```

Is writing to a document that is not the current active document not permitted? I thought that if we're allowed to create a new document then we should be able to write to it.

Comment: The error message says that `var body = myNewDoc.body;` is the line with the error, not the `insertText` line.

Comment: The error message shows that the code field is NotAllowed, and the message field is "The action isn’t supported in Word Online. Check the OfficeExtension.Error.debugInfo for more information.".

Your Word Online not support the code you write.

Unfortunately, I didn't search for any links to write content to a new document, and maybe Word.js doesn't support writing content to a new document.